# AWS EC2 - access dockerized rest api service over https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a nodejs API hosted on an EC2 instance (ubuntu server) which is running on PORT 5000.

Using http:// i can access this API over public-api:5000 but I can not access it over https.

I have opened all ports in the security group and allowed access from anywhere but still it is not possible.

What do I have to do, in order to access my API via https instead of only http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTPS to work you need TLS/SSL Certificates. Just enabling the port (default is 443 for https) will not work. You can get free TLS certs on AWS using [AWS ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) service. You should have access to Domain and should be able to update the domain records for ACM to verify your cert.

You can terminate TLS on Load Balancer or on your application. You have to handle https traffic. [Reference here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/)

Comment: Thank you. So in order for AWS EC2 https access I need a domain? I have used other services like heroku before which had https from the beginning on. Is there any other way I could make this work without getting a domain? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use Load Balancer in front of your application. AWS LB comes with a domain of its own which has HTTPS by default. So if the requirement is to only have HTTPS then using a LB is a good option. It will not be free though.  https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/

Comment: yes the requirement is only https. I dont care about the domain I need to call to access the application. I will look into this loadbalancer, thank you thus far

Comment: So I tried creating an application load balancer, created target groups for the ports and all. But once I want to create the load balancer, it says a default ssl certificate is required.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the screenshot of error